# How to get Infinite Ajax Scroll working with filtering and ordering. PHP / JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, filtering, infinite-scroll

My goal is to have a responsive page containing a list of divs which users can browse.  I need to use server side pagination using infinite scrolling.  I also want to be able to apply filters and ordering to the list.  I have spent while looking for different solutions and come across (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which looks perfect for what I want, however, in the documentation it advises against using filtering and infinite scrolling together.

Instead I have implemented the infinite-ajax-scroll (https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) plugin onto my project and decided not to filer and order using ajax as not to over complicate it (and due to limited ajax / jquery knowledge).  However this does not work, what happens is the page loads with the correct filters but then when the 2nd page loads, the filter is no longer applied.  How do I pass the filter `$cat` so that it scrolls?

Below is what I have thus far.

```
$cat = (isset($_GET['cat']) ? urldecode($_GET['cat']) : ''); 
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
$start = ($page * $pagelimit) - $pagelimit;
$limit = $pagelimit*$page; 

//get total number of discounts for search
$total_items = Stuff::countItems($cat);

if( $total_items > ($page * $limit) ){
  $next = ++$page;
}

//get items
$items = Stuff::getItems($cat, $sortby, $dir, $start, $limit);

if(!$items){
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  echo 'Page not found!';
  exit();
} 

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
            jQuery.ias({
              container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
              item: '.item', // single items
              pagination: '.paginate', // page navigation
              next: '.paginate a', // next page selector
              loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
              noneleft: 'No more items', //Contains the message to be displayed when there are no more pages left to load
              triggerPageThreshold: 5, // show "load more" if scroll more than this to stop
              trigger: "Load more items"
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">    
        <?php
        echo 'TOTAL: '.$total_items .'<br />';

        //filter through categories*/
        echo 'FILTER BY CATEGORY:';
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            $categoryURL = urlencode($category);
            echo "<a href=\"index.php?cat=$categoryURL\">$category<a/> | ";
        }       
        //loop through and display items
       foreach ($items as $id => $item){

           echo "<div style=\"border:1px solid green;margin-bottom:5px;\" class=\"item\" id=\"item-$id\">
                    ID: $id <br />
                    $item[name]<br />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    $item[cat]<br />
                    $item[description]<br />
            </div>";
        }
        ?>
    <!--paginagation-->
    <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
    <div class="paginate">
      <a href='index.php?cat=<?php echo $cat?>&p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<div class="paginate">
  <a href='index.php?cat=<?php echo urlencode($cat); ?>&p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes tried that.  In the Firefox console it shows that $cat is not being passed  ie. http://dev.local/items/index.php?cat=&p=2

Comment: Sorry it does pass the $cat value, however this does not scroll at all when this is passed.  Nothing happens in the console either.